# how to get the cursor position inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, codemirror

Im trying to do a code editor like codemirror and the problem im stuck with is stimulating the cursor inside a div element.what i did was i laid the textarea on the div content here is what i have done so far but i have no idea on how to continue.

```
'http://codepen.io/megatroncoder/pen/KzYGwY'
```

I know there are many bugs in the code but i can handle most of them.
I have seen many answers in the stackoverflow but most of them didnt help me so far.
So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At first I was going to answer with something involving changing .editor to contenteditable and raising its z-index, but that makes the cursor go inside of the colored spans. The reason a cursor is not displaying is because opacity of the textarea is 0. Perhaps I'm stating the obvious. The best compromise I could think of was to make the textarea's color white w/ half opacity, and place it exactly on top of the copied text, like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONGGxg (new CSS values are indented).

Comment: p.s. When I look at codemirror or codepen's implementation of such things in the DOM Inspector, it looks like they're just using a very small textarea only for the cursor and positioning it depending on where the user clicked.

Comment: @Max Starkenburg you are right but i made the textarea's opacity intentionally because i didnt want the textarea text to be seen.and for the code mirror they do make a small textarea but in the earlier versions they used to make the textarea cover the whole div element.so seems like there is no solution for this and i have to do this another way.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I tried to look for other examples of online syntax highlighting editors, and it seems most are either using the small textarea, or using the opacity trick (e.g. collabedit) or something else that I couldn't quite figure out (codepress).

Comment: @Max I think its just better to use one of the ready made ones since making this would require complex event handling such as getting the position of the mouse inside the div and putting up the textarea in thereand many more